# Android setText not working on TextView

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I attempting to change the value of a Textview to some information I am querying parse for, but for some reason the `.setText` is not taking affect.

I tried googling but `.getString` does not work either. I am pretty new to Parse any Advice?

my code is the following:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;


/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class productDetail extends Fragment {


public productDetail() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}






@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_detail, container, false);

    final TextView productNameLabel = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.productNameTextView);
    final TextView productDetailsLabel = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.productDetails);
    final TextView shippingFeeLabel = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.shippingFee);
    final TextView productPriceLabel = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);
    final TextView productNumberOfReviewsLabel = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.productNumberOfReviews);

    final String chosenProduct = getArguments().getString("productName");
    Log.i("AppInfo", chosenProduct);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Inventory");
    query.whereEqualTo("productName", chosenProduct);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            if (parseObject == null) {

                Integer fee = parseObject.getInt("ShippingFee");
                Integer review = parseObject.getInt("numberOfReviews");
                String information = parseObject.get("information").toString();
                Integer price = parseObject.getInt("price");


                productNameLabel.setText(chosenProduct);
                productDetailsLabel.setText(String.valueOf(information));
                shippingFeeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(fee));
                productPriceLabel.setText(String.valueOf(price));
                productNumberOfReviewsLabel.setText(String.valueOf(entries));

            }

        }
    });




    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return theView;
}

}
```

Comment: Log the value of the `parseObject` to the console & check for irregularities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything within that if statement will throw a NullPointerException if it was entered  :)

Change the if statement to this

```
if (parseObject != null)
```

Or maybe you meant this?

```
if (e == null)
```

Comment: thank you I just saw that when I tried logging the error

Comment: Welcome. I think you should be checking `e == null`,  though, right?

Comment: yea I changed it to e == null not sure how I mixed it up

Comment: It happens. I updated the answer. Good luck with your app.